# Geometrically bounded transition probability in Markov Chains

Tags: markov-chains

Consider a Markov Chain with finitely many transition states. Show there is $M>0$ and $\alpha<1$ such that $p_{ij}^{(n)}\leq M\alpha^n$ for all $n$, whenever $i,j$ are transient states.

I was thinking of considering $\displaystyle \sup_{i,j \text{ transient}}p_{ij}=\alpha$. Now I tried to do induction but that didn't seem to work out.
$$p_{ij}^{(n+1)}=\sum_{k\in S}p_{ik}^{(n)}p_{kj}$$ I tried to utilise this, but to no avail. Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd start like this: if $j$ is transient, then $p_{ij}^{(n)}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. So you can choose $N$ large enough so that $\alpha:=\sup_{i,j} p_{ij}^{(N)}<1.$ The supremum is over the transient states $i$ and $j$.

Comment: The only thing left to add is that $\alpha<1$ because there are finitely many transient states.